# Dropdowns not closing on other item clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have some `dropdowns` that contain multiple elements that I would like to collapse if open when any other menu item is clicked. Here is what I have so far:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Master CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JS  -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="sidebar" id="sidebar-id">
      <ul class="list-unstyled nav components">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#aboutSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i>About</a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="aboutSubmenu">
            <li><a href="#">Pages 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pages 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pages 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#pagesSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></i>Pages</a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pagesSubmenu">
            <li><a href="#">Pages 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pages 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pages 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i> Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i>Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- end sidebar -->
</body>
```

As you can see when you click on 'About' or 'Pages' their dropdown opens, however they do not close unless you click on the specific heading again. I would like any open dropdown to close, unless you click on the dropdowns heading, in which case all dropdowns will close and then the correct dropdown shall open.

Comment: If you want this behaviour I'd suggest using an accordion instead of a list: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Would something like that be suitable for use in navigation? It's a sidebar that's used as a navbar on the site.

Comment: Given that it replicates the exact behaviour you are trying to achieve I don't see why it would be an issue

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Would there be no simple `jQuery` that I could use to close all dropdowns, then open the selected one?..

Comment: Sure, just call `slideUp()` on the relevant elements when another one of them is slid down - but the whole point of using Bootstrap properly is that you don't need to do it yourself

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I'm conflicted now in that if I use the  accordion I am unsure of how to style it to look like the list I have, or if I use the jquery I am using elements I don't necessarily need to..

Comment: That's pretty much your choice. The first is to use the accordion, but potentially have to re-do something you've already done, or patch in the functionality to have a less-than-ideal solution. The former is by far the better choice

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  if(!$(this).next('ul').hasClass('in')) {
    $('.collapse').each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('in');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="wrapper">
<nav class="sidebar" id="sidebar-id">
  <ul class="list-unstyled nav components">
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#aboutSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i>About</a>
      <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="aboutSubmenu">
        <li><a href="#">Pages 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pages 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pages 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#pagesSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></i>Pages</a>
      <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pagesSubmenu">
        <li><a href="#">Pages 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pages 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pages 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i> Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Seems to work the first few times but then 'Pages' tends to get stuck and won't open any longer..

Comment: @CBreeze Check the updated answer, issue may be with `slideUp`. So I change it to removeClass.